# Connect SQL Server and MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server, linux, windows, sql-server-2005

I've a SQL Server 2005 on a Windows PC and I also have a MySQL database on another Linux server.

I'm looking for a way to combine both databases under a 3rd server, to run respective queries and update them on this 3rd server, upon data being updated a trigger will automatically push the update to the remote servers (SQL Servers and MySQL).

I want to execute queries through PHP and I was thinking to sync the databases to this third server and then push the modified values toward server 1 with SQL Server and server 2 with MySQL.

Suggestions are welcomed :)

Comment: 2005 is long deprecated. For SQL Server you can use linked servers

Comment: Yeah i know its depricated :( , but the custom software which is using that database , hasnt had any maintenance in years. I just need to be able to query out data, and select/update/delete very basic operations on the tables of mssql.

Comment: I really do suggest upgrading. If the application you use isn't supported anymore either, then doubly it means it's time to move on, as you've using 2 end of life applications.